# how to setup php code to use ssl with https connection

Tags: php, ssl, https

I'm working on my first web site that requires SSL, it's hosted on a PCI Compliant server, SSL is setup correctly (or so I've been told).

I was hoping that I could just change a particular link in my code to go to a page, such as https://mydomain.com/login.php, but alas, it doesn't work. It doesn't even say that a SSL cert is present.

After some reading I'm thinking I must use curl to correctly work with HTTPS correct? If this is the case, are there any good 'still valid' tutorials on this topic?

Also, my hosting company said I was using php modules(I'm assuming he's referring to functions) that aren't compatible with their systems, they must work with 5.3.x...well I went through an entire page of code they claimed wasn't compatible, and every single function was in the php 5.3.x supported functions list (http://php.net/quickref.php).

Any insight into what they mean here? This stuff shouldn't seem like rocket science, but I'm coming up short on figuring it out correctly, and implementing http with SSL.

Thanks!

Comment: If the webserver is set up that way, all you'd need to do is use an `https://` URL instead of an `http://` URL. There's no need to involve curl at all. Can you specify in more detail what the problem is with that approach?

Comment: when you go to https://mydomain.com/login.php, what happens?

Comment: I just used an SSL checker, and it appears they need to install an intermediate certificate in order for the installed SSL certificate to be trusted on some browser and give me the lock icon I need to be seeing. So much for 'my modules'...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of this.  If mydomain.com/login.php is working but https://mydomain.com/login.php is not then it is not setup.  Also you might want to see if https://www.mydomain.com/login.php works.  It depends on what was setup as the fully qualified domain name in the certificate and key.

Usually servers have a default self signed certificate and it will give you a warning in browsers when trying to go to https.  Is that what you are getting?? Or a different error?

Hope this gives you some direction...If it isn't setup you can go to the CA for directions on install directions.

Comment: Ok, this is precisely the way I thought it should work as well. This guy calls himself a 'fellow developer'.

Comment: If you go to http:// www.mydomain.com/login.php all works fine. If you go to https:// www.mydomain.com/login.php you receive a security warning that states: 'the site attempts to identify itself with invalid information'. In chrome it says 'The site's security certificate is not trusted!'. I'm starting to think that this guy has absolutely no idea what he's talking about, and that they somehow screwed up the SSL certificate.